# React native Cannot connect to react-devtools using android simulator

Tags: android, react-native, react-devtools

I execute the project with `react-native run-android` and in another terminal, i do:

`npm run react-devtools`

and it opens the new window of electron that says:

> The react native app it will open in a few seconds...

but nothing happens.

I put in the simulator toggle inspector with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> and i can see in networks that it makes a request to `http://localhost:8097` and the result is it fails to connect and keeps trying with the same result.

The window of electron that is open it says that it wait connections to the port **8097** so i can see is trying to connect but with no results!

Answer (score 33):

You need to run this command in a new terminal `adb reverse tcp:8097 tcp:8097`

Comment: Note that, though some docs say this is only necessary when *not* using local simulators, it is also necessary with some local simulators, specifically Android 12 simulators, which restrict port forwarding.

Answer (score 5):

react-devtools v4 is incompatible with react-native

try version 3 instead of version 4:
`npm install -d -g react-devtools@3.x`, it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Unemployed3494 didn't work for me. Instead I killed all running processes belonging to my Mac OS user with this command:

`pkill -u username`

After doing so, react devtools connected as expected to the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I have run yarn start before. I canceled it and run devtools again and it works now.