# Devtools failed to connect to react native emulator

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, devtools, react-devtools

I execute the project with react-native run-android and in another terminal, i do:

npm run react-devtools

and it opens the new window of electron that says:

The react native app it will open in a few seconds...

but nothing happens.

I put in the simulator toggle inspector with Ctrl + m and i can see in networks that it makes a request to http://localhost:8097 and the result is it fails to connect and keeps trying with the same result.

devtools can not to connect to emulator, It write connecting... And show a link for troubleshoot but link doesnt work. With ctrl shift i in devtools, I can understand error is fail to connect because of backend.js. Can Any body help me?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867874/react-native-cannot-connect-to-react-devtools-using-android-simulator

Answer (score 0):

Make sure pors is forwarded from the emulator.
Use `adb reverse tcp:8097 tcp:8097` to enable
See https://fig.io/manual/adb/reverse for more details