# react-devtools for react-native

Tags: react-native, react-devtools

Recently I started developing in react-native. When trying to debug using the react-devtools extension on the browser (Chrome) I only get access to the console, because all the components and elements are the ones displayed in the devtools web-page (http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/)
So now I am trying using the react-native standalone version but it is "waiting for React to connect.."
and I get a message at the bottom saying "The server is listening on the port 8097".

I don't know much about ports but it looks to me that the application is on one port (8081) whereas the react-devtools is listening to another (8097).

I tried using `adb reverse tcp:8097 tcp:8097` before running the react-devtools but it made no difference.

How do I check what port my app is listening to?

How can I make the standalone devtools run?

And if anyone can link me to a good documentation about ports for people with no background it would be very nice as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native Cannot connect to react-devtools using android simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867874/react-native-cannot-connect-to-react-devtools-using-android-simulator)

Answer (score 2):

you are on the right track, after assigning port 8097.

Run <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to open the development menu and it is automatically detected by `react-devtools`.