# Can I use CSS/style devtools for a React Native app?

Tags: css, react-native, react-devtools

I'm running a React Native app in the iPhone simulator on macOS and I've been able to get standalone `react-devtools` to work but I haven't found a way to get browser devtools style/CSS editing to work. It seems this app only provides access to the `Components` and `Profiler` tabs, which makes sense.

As stated in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167357/react-devtools-for-react-native), "when trying to [access styles and CSS editing devtools] using the react-devtools extension on the browser (Chrome, Safari, or Firefox) I only get access to the console, because all the components and elements are the ones displayed in the devtools web-page".

Is it possible to inspect and update styles of my React Native application running in an iPhone simulator?

(if this is possible with the Android emulator then I'm interested in a solution for that as well)

Comment: Have you tried react-native-debugger or flipper?

Comment: Ya, looks like both of these do not have CSS viewing/editing abilities.

Comment: Everytime you change something and save it, it will updates

Comment: @user16967562 CSS/style devtools provide a much more comprehensive set of advantages than just updating the page on save.

Answer (score 0):

CSS inspecting and debugging *is* actually built-in to the standalone React Developer Tools and React Native Inspector, but it's not intuitive to find.

- CSS styles are rendered *below* the normal React DevTools "props" panel for a component. So if you have a long prop list/devTools is in a small window, you may need to scroll down to see them.
- Styles applied via a theme **will not appear in the "style" panel**, but rather under the `style` prop in the "props" panel.

Hopefully the screenshot will clarify a bit. Once you do find them, they're editable from the panel, just like in normal browser DevTools.

[image]

(I'm using the Android emulator, but in theory it should be the same for iOS.)